# Liquibase changes the url from jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3307/db to jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/db

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I'm trying to generate changelog from an existing database using liquibase. But, whenever I run the cmd `mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog` it exits with the following exception
**liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Don't know how to query for sequences on root @ jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/db (Default Schema: agence_directe_server)**

My config is as follow:
liquibase.properties

```yaml
driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3307/db
```

pom.xml

```xml
        <spring-boot.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <liquibase-core.version>3.8.9</liquibase-core.version>
        <liquibase-maven-plugin.version>3.8.9</liquibase-maven-plugin.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.8</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
        <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
        <javassist.version>3.23.1-GA</javassist.version>
        <jaxb-api.version>2.3.1</jaxb-api.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Liquibase maven plugin does not read application.yml to know how to connect to your database, it has its own configuration in your pom.xml. So you have to put it there." from: https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50723923.shtml.

Comment: I've been doing so and it didn't work. It's solved by adding jpa and validation-api as dependencies for the plugin.